# Update data in laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I try to create crud in laravel 6. Create, Read and Delete process is running well. But when Update process, the data in table not change. Could anyone help me to find the problem ? The following my code.

Route

```
Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@index');
Route::get('/blog/add','BlogController@add');
Route::post('/blog/store','BlogController@store');
Route::get('/blog/edit/{id}','BlogController@edit');
Route::post('/blog/update','BlogController@update');
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $blog = DB::table('blog')->get();
        return view('blog',['blog' => $blog]);
    }


public function edit($id)
    {       
        $blog = DB::table('blog')->where('blog_id', $id)->get(); 
        return view('edit', ['blog'=>$blog]);
    }

public function update(Request $request)
    {
        DB::table('blog')->where('blog_id',$request->blog_id)->update([
        'blog_title' => $request->title,
        'author' => $request->author]);

return redirect('/blog');
        }
```

View

```
@foreach ($blog as $n)
<form method="post" action="/blog/update" />
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      Title <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $n->title}}"> 
      Author<input type="text" name="author" value="{{ $n->author}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Update</button>
  </form>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Nothing in your Laravel log? You are missing a `@method('patch')` in your form. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Try changing $request->blog_id to $request->input('blog_id'); and you dont post that id with your action="/blog/update". maybe change that to: /blog/update/{{ $n->id }}

Comment: I have tried change but still error

Answer (score 0):

```
You must provide id in your route

Route::post('/blog/update/{id}','BlogController@update');


In update method add parameter id and then find product against id 

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
DB::table('blog')->where('blog_id',$id)->update([
'blog_title' => $request->title,
'author' => $request->author]);
return redirect('/blog');
}

@foreach ($blog as $n)
<form method="post" action="{{ route('your route name'), ['id' => $$n->id] }}" />
{{ csrf_field() }}
Title <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $n->title}}"> 
Author<input type="text" name="author" value="{{ $n->author}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Update</button>
</form>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You mean we have to add id in table? I am using blog_id as primary key.

Comment: no need to add new id column use blog_id instead of id

Answer (score 0):

try separating the update into two statements like so

```
$blog = DB::table('blog')->where('blog_id',$id)->first();
$blog->update([
'blog_title' => $request->title,
'author' => $request->author]);
```

Also you might want to use models in the future so you can do it like

```
$blog = Blog::where('blog_id',$id)->first();
```

Doesn't really shorten your code but it improves the readibility.

Answer (score 0):

Do your update like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $post = DB::table('blog')->where('blog_id',$request->blog_id)->first();
    $post->blog_title = $request->title;
    $post->author = $request->author;
    $post->update();
    return redirect('/blog');
    }
```